# Using SQL IN statement based on case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to use `in` command based on case statement

I have tried something like this

```
@Id int

Select * 
From Table 
Where  StatusId in( case when Id =1 then 1 else 1,3 end)
```

and

```
    Select * 
    From Table 
    Where  StatusId in case when Id =1 then (1) else (1,3) end
```

Any Ideas!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need to solve this in a different way:

```
Where (Id = 1 and StatusId in (1)) or (Id <> 1 and StatusId in (1, 3))
```

Variations of this pattern are possible.

Comment: This question comes up so frequently, there really should be links to these types of questions in the SQL or SQL Server tag wiki.  Note to self... +1 in any case!

Answer (score 2):

For your example you can simply do:

```
where StatusId = 1 or (Id <> 1 and StatusId = 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL a query like this works:

```
Select * from 
Table
where case when Id = 1 then StatusId = 1
    else StatusId in (1,3) end;
```

Try this and let me know if it worked, thanks

Comment: That tag for this question is for `sql-server-2008`, not `mysql`.

Comment: Yeah..but i haven't got sql-server-2008 to verify if it works. checked it over mysql.

Comment: This query doesn't work for SQL Server, which is what the user is asking for.